# Screen and kitty what should $TERM be?

Tags: environment-variables, tmux, gnu-screen, kitty

Why does `tmux` report

```
$TERM=screen-256color
```

Normally `kitty` reports

```
$TERM=xterm-kitty
```

Which should I use if I run `tmux` inside `kitty`? Obviously `kitty` provides advanced functionality and that makes sense that it reports `xterm-kitty`. Why does screen report that it's `screen-256` are there programs that need to be aware that they're running in screen? Would it be problematic to call screen running in kitty `xterm-kitty`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Which should I use if I run tmux inside kitty?*

When running `tmux` then you *must* use `TERM=screen`, `TERM=tmux`, or one of the derivatives e.g. `TERM=screen-256color` or `TERM=tmux-256color`.

man `tmux(1)` states ...

> The TERM environment variable must be set to “screen” for all programs running inside tmux.  New windows will automatically have “TERM=screen” added to their environment, but care must be taken not to reset this in shell start-up files.

.. and further down clarifies ...

> Set the default terminal for new windows created in this session - the default value of the TERM environment variable.  For tmux to work correctly, this must be set to ‘screen’ or a derivative of it.

... they also emphasize *must*.

The [tmux wiki](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki/FAQ) continues with additional clarification and answers ...

> Inside tmux TERM must be "screen", "tmux" or similar (such as "tmux-256color").
>   Don't bother reporting problems where it isn't!

*Are there programs that need to be aware that they're running in screen?*

Yes. Many programs, such as `tput`, will not display correctly when they're running in `screen` (or `tmux`) unless they're using the correct `TERM` value.

> **What is TERM and what does it do?**
>
> The environment variable TERM tells applications the name of a terminal description to read from the terminfo(5) database. Each description consists of a number of named capabilities which tell applications what to send to control the terminal. For example, the "cup" capability contains the escape sequence used to move the cursor up.
>
> ***It is important that TERM points to the correct description for the terminal an application is running in - if it doesn't, applications may misbehave.***
>
> The infocmp(1) command shows the contents of a terminal description and the tic(1) command builds and installs a description from a file (the -x flag is normally required with both).

*Would it be problematic to call screen running in kitty xterm-kitty?*

Not necessarily, as long as the `TERM` value in the running screen is set correctly (i.e. `TERM=screen-256color`) and there's valid terminfo strings for it that `screen` or `tmux` knows how to handle.

Other derivatives (on my machine) are:

```
/usr/share/terminfo/s/screen
/usr/share/terminfo/s/screen-16color
/usr/share/terminfo/s/screen-256color
/usr/share/terminfo/s/screen.Eterm
/usr/share/terminfo/s/screen.gnome
/usr/share/terminfo/s/screen.konsole
/usr/share/terminfo/s/screen.linux
/usr/share/terminfo/s/screen.mlterm
/usr/share/terminfo/s/screen.mrxvt
/usr/share/terminfo/s/screen.rxvt
/usr/share/terminfo/s/screen.teraterm
/usr/share/terminfo/s/screen.vte
/usr/share/terminfo/s/screen.xterm-r6
/usr/share/terminfo/s/screen.xterm-new
/usr/share/terminfo/s/screen.xterm-xfree86
```

Once `TERM` is set, you could run `infocmp`.  That will report if there's a valid terminfo for the value.  Other tests can validate basic terminfo functionality, such as:

`for terminfos in $(find /usr/share/terminfo/s -type f -name 'screen*' -printf '%f\n' -o -name 'tmux*' -printf '%f\n'); do export TERM=$terminfos; printf "%s: %sthis is foreground color 10 %sitalics%s and now all attributes are turned off\n" "$terminfos" "$(tput setaf 10)" "$(tput sitm)" "$(tput sgr0)"; done`

Comment: That last answer from superuser is less than useful.  screen's emulating something that's a particular terminal type more/less for consistency.  tmux uses the same terminal description to (try to) not rely upon a new terminal description being installed.  Ultimately that doesn't work well, but for reasons outside the scope of this question.

Answer (score 1):

Kitty's advanced functionality isn't compatible with things like `tmux`. For example if you run `tmux` and then run

```
$ kitty icat ~/Pictures/fc.jpg 
Terminal does not support reporting screen sizes via the TIOCGWINSZ ioctl
$ TERM=xterm-kitty kitty icat ~/Pictures/fc.jpg 
Terminal does not support reporting screen sizes via the TIOCGWINSZ ioctl
```

So you can see even if you fudge `TERM` under tmux to match the one Kitty reports, you'll find a dead end, at best. Under ranger, range just crashes when trying to render a preview.

Comment: I'm a bit confused why the answer addresses tmux when the bulk of the question focuses on screen?

Comment: If kitty doesn't support the ioctl, that's a bug.  But it's unrelated to the `TERM` value.

Comment: @JeffSchaller the question is 100% about tmux, tmux just reports its term is screen. But, I did have one typo =)

Answer (score 0):

That's several questions.  Here are answers for the more interesting ones:

> - Why does tmux report
>
>   `$TERM=screen-256color`

Older releases of tmux use TERM=screen or TERM=screen-256color "because it's there".  Ultimately that changed (a) because tmux's developer wanted to add features and (b) because screen interferes with using italics.

> - Normally kitty reports
>
>   `$TERM=xterm-kitty`
>
>   Which should I use if I run tmux inside kitty?

You should let tmux choose (it looks at the outer terminal description to see how to handle color and function-keys).

> - Why does screen report that it's screen-256

Probably meant to say "screen-256color".  GNU screen looks at the outer $TERM value and chooses an inner one.  But this particular one comes from the user's .screenrc file (normally - packagers may get involved).

> - are there programs that need to be aware that they're running in screen?

Not really...

> - Would it be problematic to call screen running in kitty xterm-kitty?

Some **`screen`** configurations use bce (back color erase) by default.  kitty doesn't support the feature (ymmv).